# Tear in radial gradient background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to cover the entire body of my website in a radial background, but I'm getting 'tears' (from lack of a better name). Seeing is believing, as they say, so rather than describing it further, go here to see it in all its glory: [www.jorum.se](http://www.jorum.se).

I'll add an image for reference in case someone else has the same problem in the future.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html body {
    height:100%;
}
```

Simple as that!

Comment: It works until you scroll, then the background repeats. Checked by adding your CSS in Firebug and zooming out. Adding `background-position:bottom;background-attachment:fixed;` seemed to fix it.